# Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction by Leonid Shifrin — corrupted PDF

Tags: warning-messages, reference-request

I wanted to use the PDF of *Mathematica programming: an advanced introduction* by Leonid Shifrin because I can quickly search through a PDF, and also read it off-line.

Leonid Shifrin, the author, has the book at http://mathprogramming-intro.org/

I downloaded the PDF
http://mathprogramming-intro.org/download/MathProgrammingIntro.pdf

There is a problem with the PDF. I am using the current Adobe Acrobat Professional DC (AGM Version 4.030.00072).

The PDF wants a signature. However, Acrobat says the signature request in the PDF is corrupted. Because of the error, Acrobat continually displays a yellow bar which you cannot close.

Is everyone having the same problem?

I emailed the author, but did not receive a reply.

leonid@mathprogramming-intro.org
bugs@mathprogramming-intro.org

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Properties | Security tab does not allow document changes.

Does anyone know how to contact Shifrin?

Comment: I will look into that, but you are the first one to report this problem. Are you sure it is not on your side (your reader)? I have not touched the pdf pretty much since I uploaded it back in 2009.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70016/discussion-between-leonid-shifrin-and-john).

Comment: I just found the Adobe Reader on an Android tablet works without the error.

Hopefully, you can remove the signature stuff from the original PDF so this problem will not occur. I think the latest version of Adobe Acrobat does not like the signature stuff unless it was created using Adobe Acrobat itself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that's good to know.