# Reference request: Are there any recent books written in the same spirit as David Wagner's Power programming?

Tags: reference-request

I enjoyed a lot the idea of David Wagner's book, focused in performance and tells you why some code is faster than the naive alternative, going to the inner workings of the kernel, which for me makes it easier to remember. However there are some things out of date, since the book was written at the time of version 3, are there any recent books with the same spirit? (Honestly, I believe that it should be the company's responsibility to keep new versions of books like that. There are tons of introductory books, which is great, but something in the spirit of Wagner's book is needed if one is interested in bringing heavy workflows to Mathematica)

Comment: I have [few book on Mathematica](https://12000.org/book_collection/indexsection7.htm)  (do not look at them much anymore, since it is much easier to search for something using the internet and the help system) but I really liked **Mathematica Navigator** by Heikki Ruskeepaa. He stopped making new editions long time ago (2004).  My guess is that Mathematica got so large to keep up with it. Good book to learn from. May be not same spirit was Wagner's.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161717/mathematica-programming-an-advanced-introduction-by-leonid-shifrin-corrupted . It is of similar style and free.

Comment: @Acus I think that book is not currently available. See https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2762/is-leonid-shifrin-ok-these-days. Or do you know another source?

Comment: @Goofy Even the page where your book was hosted, now my antivirus recognizes it as potentially dangerous.

Comment: @Goofy Few minute search revealed https://archive.org/details/ost-computer-science-mathprogrammingintro  which can be reached from https://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=8101  Just tested.